# Build/Deploy Failed in Azure

Tags: azure, web

Add or update the App Service deployment workflow configuration from … Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App. My app wont deploy on azure for some reason.

```
deploy
Deployment Failed with Error: Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
Site Unavailable (CODE: 503)
```

Answer (score 0):

For a 503 error, I'd do the following:

- Start by just restarting the site. If you're getting a 503, it's in a bad state. See what happens.
- In the Azure Portal, go to the Web App management blade. Click on Diagnose and Solve Problems. There's lots of utilities and reports that might shed some light.
- Go to the Metrics menu. You can check to see if you're suffering from resource exhaustion. Try CPU utilization and memory utilization.
- Go to App Service Logs. Turn on Application Logging, Web Server Logging, Detailed Error Messages, and Failed Request Tracing. Failed Request Tracing is particularly applicable for 503 errors.